# Tips on Improving Efficiency of this Code (Beginner)

Tags: c++

I am currently doing a coding exercise and am missing some cases due to the time limit being exceeded. Can I get some tips on how to improve the efficiency of my code? Also if you have any general tips for a beginner I would also appreciate that. The problem is below and thanks.

You are given all numbers between 1,2,…,n except one. Your task is to find the missing number.

Input

The first input line contains an integer n.

The second line contains n−1 numbers. Each number is distinct and between 1 and n (inclusive).

Output

Print the missing number.

Constraints
2≤n≤2⋅105
Example

Input:

```
5
2 3 1 5
```

Output:

```
4
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int missingNumber(vector<int> available, int N) {
    for (int i=1; i<=N; i++) {
        bool counter = false;
        for (int j=0; j<N-1; j++) {
            if (i == available[j]) {
                counter = true;    
            }
        }
        if (counter == false) {
            return i;    
        }
    }    
}

int main() {
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0); cin.tie(0);
    int N;
    cin >> N;
    vector<int> available(N-1);
    int temp = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<N-1; i++) {
        cin >> temp;
        available[i] = temp;
    }
    cout << missingNumber(available, N);
}
```

Comment: When you get "time limit exceeded" it usually means you need a better algorithm.

Comment: It is a very classical exercise. For example: take the XOR `^ ` of all input numbers `x`, then XOR of all numbers from 1 to n  `y`, and then take `x ^ y`. Complexity O(n), and not O(n^2) as your code.

Comment: Apart from considering another algorithm there are two simple improvements you can do, and both are generally good practice:  
Pass `available` by reference (to avoid copying the data), and `break;` the inner loop after finding the value.

Comment: @Damien could you please provide further information on this algorithm (the name of it, links, implementations, ...)? I'm having a hard time understanding it.

Comment: @Timo I don't know the name. I am sure I have already seen it on SO. I might even had already answered it. I could not find it. The point is that `a ^ a = 0` whatever `a`. For example, `x = 1 ^ 2 ^ 3 ^ 5 = 5`, `y = 1 ^ 2 ^ 3 ^ 4 ^ 5 = 1`, and finally `x ^ y = 1^ 5 = 4`

Answer (score 2):

A very simple solution with O(N) complexity is based on the observation that if the N-1 numbers are all between 1 and N and distinct from each other, then it suffices to:

1. compute the sum of all these N-1 numbers, so linear complexity
2. subtract the sum computed at step 1 from the sum of the N numbers from 1 to N, which we know is N * (N + 1) / 2, so O(1) complexity.

Answer (score 1):

here is an answer with two versions to your problem

the first version is using `Arithmetic progression formula` `n*(a1 + an) /2`
and then subtract your vector sum with the result of the formula.

```
double missingNumber_ver1(std::vector<int> available, int N) {
    // formula for sum for Arithmetic progression
    double sum = N * (available[0]+available[N-2]) /2;
    double available_sym = std::accumulate(available.begin(), available.end(), 0); // this is to sum the giving numbers
    double missing_num = sum-available_sym;
    return missing_num;
}
```

the second version is to use `XOR` operator and when there is a xor value that is not 0 that means this is the missing number. I'm also using [std::iota](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota) to build the comparison vector with range values.

```
double missingNumber_ver2(std::vector<int> available, int N) {
      std::vector<int>tem_vec(N-1);  
      std::iota(tem_vec.begin(), tem_vec.end(), available[0]);
      auto av_it = available.begin();
      auto tem_vec_it = tem_vec.begin();
      while(!(*av_it ^ *tem_vec_it))
      {
        av_it++;
        tem_vec_it++;
      }
      return *tem_vec_it;
    }
```

and here is the full code - look that I made few changes also in the `main()` function

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <numeric>
 #include <vector>

double missingNumber_ver1(std::vector<int> available, int N) {
    // formula for sum for Arithmetic progression
    double sum = N * (available[0]+available[N-2]) /2;
    double available_sym = std::accumulate(available.begin(), available.end(), 0);
    double missing_num = sum-available_sym;
    return missing_num;
}

double missingNumber_ver2(std::vector<int> available, int N) {
  std::vector<int>tem_vec(4);
  std::iota(tem_vec.begin(), tem_vec.end(), available[0]);
  auto av_it = available.begin();
  auto tem_vec_it = tem_vec.begin();
  while(!(*av_it ^ *tem_vec_it))
  {
    av_it++;
    tem_vec_it++;
  }
  return *tem_vec_it;
}


int main() {
    int N;
    std::cin >> N;
    std::vector<int> available;
    int temp = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<N-1; i++) {
        std::cin >> temp;
        available.push_back(temp);
    }
    std::cout << "missingNumber_ver1 " << missingNumber_ver1(available, N) << "\n";
    std::cout << "missingNumber_ver2 " <<missingNumber_ver2(available, N) << "\n";
}
```